# Why are these two HDRI backgrounds different when they have the same settings?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color, hdri

I dragged a HDRI sky into my project as the world background and it has a very high contrast.
If i do the same thing in a new project it comes out how i want it, what could this be?

[image: desired normal contrast]

[image: high undesired contrast]

[image: desired image settings]

[image: undesired image settings]

Comment: could you show the two settings and how you put them in your scene?

Comment: I've just edited the post to include photos, are there any more settings you would like me to post specifically? Thanks for your efforts! :)

Comment: Sampling settings are different, try adjusting that

Comment: From the shader nodes alone, it shouldn't make a difference. Maybe you simply don't use the same render engine between the two files? Otherwise, I suspect the difference is in the render settings. Although I'd be surprised if sampling or bounce settings would produce such a difference. However, I wonder if your current project has any form of color grading different from your default scene options. Look in Properties Editor > Render tab > Color Management. I bet you don't have the same options there.

Comment: I would suspect the _Color Management_ as well as @L0Lock does. While the one sky looks "normal", the other looks overexposed and more saturated / contrasted. So if one is your project and the other a new scene, I guess in your project the settings are different then in your default startup file. So check the _Color Management_ for the settings, especially _View Transform_, _Look_ and _Exposure_.

Comment: @Emir _Sampling_ does not change the exposure. It's the resolution of the sampling map and changing it has effect on memory consumption, noise and render time.

Comment: @L0Lock Thank you! This fixed it, it was a difference in the colour management settings, appreciate it!

Comment: Awesome! I posted an answer with more details and broader possible issues/fixes so that anyone with a similar issue can find a solution. Please accept it as answer and upvote.

Comment: Thank you again! Ive made it the answer and will upvote once i get enough credits (im new haha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check if they are the same when you have different renders:

1. **Materials**. If only parts of your scene differ, it's probably the main issue. Could be the nodes links, the nodes' settings, but also the materials properties (Properties Editor > Materials tab > Properties). If everything in the scene looks different, then unless you have a volume shader in your world's shader, it's probably not the culprit.
2. **Render engine**. Easy to overlook, but Eevee and Cycles don't produce the same result.
3. **Color grading**. That's what influences the entire scene's colors. So if everything is different, that's one of the possible culprits (Properties Editor > Render tab > Color Management)
4. **Compositing**. (note: as of today, this one can be the culprit only if the difference is visible on render and not from the viewport. But once the [real-time compositor](https://code.blender.org/2022/07/real-time-compositor/) is implemented, you could have this issue visible from the viewport).
5. **Render settings** are different (samples, light bounces, clamps). Although this one will cause a different kind of visual difference.